# How to create a formula for a dynamic string in a column with dynamic sequence numbering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I construct the formula to get the below desired output.

[image]

Currently, the formula will give the current output with the sequence order numbering of the column F (Sub-processname), but the issue is when the Project type column row in between starts with "New" the sequence order numbering should start again from sequence number 1 followed by same sub-process name that is (Example in image :- pc3-1,pc5-1), in between if there is "Existing" with new sub process name then the number changes to 2 or 3 based on new sub process name(Example in image pc4-2, pc4 is there in first column that is Request code).

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F$2:F2,F2)=1,MAX(G$1:G1)+1,VLOOKUP(F2,F$1:G1,2,0))
```

The above formula is used in G column but that will only validate F column, but I need B column also should be included to get the correct dynamic sequence number, is it possible to achieve this through formula ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand the logic. Obviously, the first 3 characters of `Desired output` are the values in `Request code`. But what is the logic of the single digit? I just understand that it must be 1 if `Project type` is 'New'. Please explain.

Comment: @Stringeater will explain the above image example, if the Project type is New the numbering starts with -1 and will add -2 if there is New sub process  under the same New project type else if there is duplicate sub process under same New project type then continue with same New project type number that is here -1, this will go on until it encounters New project type from there again renumbering starts if there is New sub process else it will continue with -1 if there are duplicates.I hope I made sense, let me know

Comment: Punctuation please. It's easier to guess what you are trying to achieve by reading your formula than by reading your comment. Basically you need a counter that label each new unique value of `Sub-Process name` column; that until the next "New" appearance i column in `Project type` which will reset the counter to 1.

Comment: You tagged both Excel 2007 and 2010 which version should it be compatible to? Obviously not both. Also, your data can be posted as markdown table instead of a screenshot https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# also better explain the logic in your post, not in the comments.

Comment: @P.b well i tagged to both since i left the formula might work on any versions of excel.Definitely will use markdown table haven't used that before..thanks for highlighting the same

Comment: There's differences in the versions of Excel. The more recent your Excel, the more and better possible solutions. What version are you on, Office 365?

Comment: @P.b yes office 365 hope the above query looks achievable hope it can be done ?

Comment: Then look into XLOOKUP instead of VLOOKUP. You can have it search from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a single-cell-formula-based solution, this crazy formula should do the trick:

```
=A2&"-"&IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New")<>COUNTIF($B$1:B1,"New"),1,IFERROR(MID(INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(F2,INDIRECT("F"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",F1)),0)),FIND("-",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(F2,INDIRECT("F"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",F1)),0)))+1,999),AGGREGATE(14,6,MID(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),FIND("-",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B100)/($B$1:$B100="New"),COUNTIF($B$1:B2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))+1,999)*1,1)+1))
```

It covers a list from B1 to B100. If you want to increase the coverage, in the formula change the reference `$B$1:$B100` accordingly.

---

**POST-COMMENTS EDIT**

Here is the formula updated accordingly to the comments:

```
=A2&"-"&IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New")<>COUNTIF($C$1:C1,"New"),1,IFERROR(MID(INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)),FIND("-",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))+1,FIND(".",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))-FIND("-",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))-1),AGGREGATE(14,6,MID(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),FIND("-",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))+1,FIND(".",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))-FIND("-",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C100)/($C$1:$C100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))-1)*1,1)+1))&"."&D2
```

---

**2nd POST-COMMENTS EDIT**

I can find no way to make a single formula to obtain the new objective. It can be achieved placing this formula in cell B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$1:C2,"New",$E$1:E2,E2)>0,A2&"-"&IF(C2="New",1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New")/($E$1:$E$100=E2),COUNTIFS($C$1:C2,"New",$E$1:E2,E2))&"C"&RIF.COLONNA(E2)&":R[-1]C"&RIF.COLONNA(E2),FALSE),E2)+1)&"."&D2,H2)
```

And this one (which is basically the previous one) in cell H2:

```
=A2&"-"&IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New")<>COUNTIF($C$1:C1,"New"),1,IFERROR(MID(INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)),FIND("-",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))+1,FIND(".",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))-FIND("-",INDEX(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),MATCH(G2,INDIRECT("G"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&":"&CELL("address",G1)),0)))-1),AGGREGATE(14,6,MID(INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE),FIND("-",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))+1,FIND(".",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))-FIND("-",INDIRECT("R"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$100)/($C$1:$C$100="New"),COUNTIF($C$1:C2,"New"))&"C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))-1)*1,1)+1))&"."&D2
```

Comment: well your crazy formula works wonders!!, this is what exactly I require, only now I want your help is to add new column in between A and B column and move the Desired output column from the last row to B column in that case C column will have project type, and additional thing which I want to add here is that Version column (here it is C column) to be added a the end of the formula **"&"."&C2** that means the Desired output should look like this **"pc3-1.0"** and **"pc5-1.1"**, kindly help me on this so I can accept this answer, hope it is achievable ?

Comment: To move the column from I to B should be easy. Try just to cut and paste the entire column. References should adjust properly. The second part is not that simple, but i guess it's achievable. I'll most likely have to edit the `FIND` part which search for the previous results to extract the maximum value. Just to be sure: is this the ultimate goal? The main downside of such crazy formulas is that they are not easy to edit (or debugged). And btw: tecnically i don't have to grant further edit for you to accept the answer since it does answer the original question. ;) Still i'll probably [...]

Comment: [...] figure out something tomorrow just for the fun of it.

Comment: "adding the end of the formula "&"."&C2 that means the Desired output should look like this "pc3-1.0" and "pc5-1.1" the quote part is the ultimate goal of this crazy formula :-), also when I move the column from I to B the output value changed so that was my worry.. please help me on this final output.. sorry for the last minute edit..

Comment: could you please let me know if the above formula can be finished with the desired output already the solution looks like a half baked food now:-)..hope it's achievable

Comment: New formula added to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the formula you are a Gem :-) well now am in a situation where the Proj title also reappears as "Existing"Project type of any new project types then it should change the numbering to PC7-3.1 or any series number (you can see it in the above image),hope this can be achieved !!! Again and very  sorry for the last minute change and edit

Comment: You really need to improve your communication skills. Puctuations is a thing. Also words should be arranged in order to make some coherent and clear sense. Like put an "if" before the condition followed by a then to announce the subsequent action (works both in inter-personal communication and in coding). This aside: i've clearly asked you if your last request was meant to depict the ultimate goal and you said it was the final output. Now you are asking for more edit? I don't like to be lied to when they pay me, even less when i help for free. Explain your last request in a proper [...]

Comment: [...] english and i might make a final effort.

Comment: Would surely take your suggestion on the improvement of my vocabulary, sorry for the inconvenience.
As per the above attached table image, apart from the earlier result the final additional change would be as follows:
If "project title" value repeats in the same column, then the counter should start adding the suffix number. In the above scenario the value "Account" is repeated, so the "Desired output" value should be pc4-2.1,pc5-3.1,pc7-4.1,pc11-5.1 so on.. until the
same value(Account) repeats in the column, this rule applies to other "Project title" value also.

Comment: hope you are doing well!!.Hope the above scenario is achievable, let me know if you have any clarifications.

Comment: What about all the previous conditions? You initially asked for a formula to count each unique value of the same `Sub-Process name` within each "new" `Project type`. Now you are asking for a sequencing of each class of `Proj title` no matter what project they are in? I'm baffled because you are placing the result (say: the number 2 in `pc4-2.1`) in the same spot previously used for the result of the first task. Did you mean to place it somewhere else or are you completely changing your desired output? Anyway: `pc6` also has `Graphics` as `Project title`, so `pc8` should return `pc8-2-1`.

Comment: Basically, if really you are changing the desired output, your last request would be satisfy by a formula like: `=A2&"-"&COUNTIF($E$1:E2,E2)&"."&D2`

Comment: the previous formula concept of "formula to count each unique value of the same Sub-Process name within each "new" Project type" will not change it will remain as it is, this is additional change which needs to be included in the old formula, the above scenario the value "Account" is repeated after the "New" Project type and Proj title "Graphics"(i.e. pc8,7th row), for instance in the above image scenario pc8 Project type is "New" followed by Account as "Proj title" in that case the "Desired output" value should be pc11-5.0, this scenario will also apply to any "Proj title" after "New"

Comment: I'll just make a wild guess and assume that one need to count how many `Proj title` have occurred since the last lane with that same `Proj title` and a "New" in `Project type`. Then again: the result would be reported in the same spot as the previous result. That doesn't make much sense to me, but i guess one can make this new request the first level of analysis and then (if no previous combination of "New" `Project type` and the given `Proj title` has occurred) the old rules will be applied.

Comment: I guess your analysis is right, you can update the formula accordingly that will be helpful !!

Comment: New formula posted. No single-cell solution; it takes 2. Still don't understand the overall logic behind the structure of the output, but if that's what you want then be it.

Comment: Well, turned out to be the best solution for the requirement, thanks for your patience and support 